# Symfony2 : Does Dependency Injection List size have an impact on performances ?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, concept

I am simply wondering if the size of the dependency injection list size might become a problem or decrease performances.

A simple case is : Is it better to have a X services or a factory that can make X new $class ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a lot of services is not a bad thing at all, because they are not built until they are actualy needed. Services never used are never built.

Services are to encourage anytime possible, because while they do not impact your app's performances, they enable your code to be split in small blocks more easily maintained and tested.

Don't hesitate to check out the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) for more details.

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong, but I read somewhere that it's not loading all the process only if you declare them as lazyloaded. So for symfony < 2.3 it's not possible and for Symfony >= 2.3, you need to define all the services easyloaded.

Comment: It is possible to lazy load your services, yes, you have to specify `lazy : true`in your service, and that's a great thing for when your services are a bit heavy and do not need to be fully loaded. 
Anyway that does not change anything about the fact having multiple services is the way to do things, whereas keeping the entities to a minimum is the rule. It is the Occam's razor principle :
 'Entities must not be multiplied beyond necessity'